# Horizontal lines and fills on amcharts

Tags: javascript, graph, line, amcharts

I have a chart with dates on x axis and numbers -15 to 15 on the y axis.

I need to have a horizontal line at -3 and to fill the space 0 to -3 in yellow color. The only documentation I could find on amcharts that pertained to this was [this one](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/vertical-or-horizontal-lines-or-fill-ranges/) which is too little info for me.

code

```
var char = {
    type: 'xy',
    theme: 'light',

    titles: [{
        text: 'Blind PUL-QC Performance'
    }, {
        text: 'Difference: \'Blind PUL-QC(%)\' - \'Original PUL-QC(%)\'',
        bold: false
    }],

    dataProvider: als.webview.qc.reports.pullqccheck.chartDataOrig,
    valueAxes: axes2,
    graphs: graphs2,
    dataDateFormat: "DD-MM-YYYY",


        guides: [ {
            fillAlpha: 0.10,
            value: 0,
            toValue: -3,
            lineColor: "#CC0000",
            lineAlpha: 2,
            fillAlpha: 0.2,
            fillColor: "#CC0000",
            inside: true

    } ]

};
```

I am getting a fainted vertical line at the right side of the chart which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Though it doesn't show it as a code sample, the linked document does mention that you can put guides in the [valueAxis](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#guides). A quick fix is to move your `guides` into the Y value axis rather than in the top level of the chart config to get the desired result, otherwise the chart will assume the guide is placed on the X axis if you place it in the top level of the object.

```
valueAxes: [{
  position: "left",
  guides: [{
    fillAlpha: 0.10,
    value: 0,
    toValue: -3,
    lineColor: "#CC0000",
    lineAlpha: 2,
    fillAlpha: 0.2,
    fillColor: "#CC0000",
    inside: true
  }]
}, {
  // ... X axis def omitted
}]
```

Another alternative is to specify the [`valueAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide#valueAxis) id in the guide itself if you know the valueAxis' ID:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  valueAxes: [{
    id: "yaxis",
    position: "left",
    // ...
  }, {
    // ... x axis omitted
  }],
  guides: [{
    // ...
    valueAxis: "yaxis"
  }],
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/bdc743e6140eda37971fad4631ae5e2e?editors=0010)